# Java SWING - JComboBox doesn't change selection in UI when setSelectedIndex() is called

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a combobox and a button. Clicking the button will make the combobox's first item selected (index 0). But although `combo.getSelectedIndex()` has been changed(I can see it changed in debugging), in UI I cannot see it. Why?

A runnable example:

```
package com.WindThunderStudio.TableWithComboBox;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TC extends JFrame{
    JComboBox<String> combo;
    JTable table;
    public TC(){
        begin();
    }
    public void begin(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("nothing.");
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(options);
        combo = new JComboBox<>(model);
        JTable table = new JTable(new Object[2][2], new String[]{"Column One", "Column Two"});
        TableColumn col0 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        col0.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));

        JButton button = new JButton("Clear");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
        });


        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
//      getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout());

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        sp.setBounds(0,0,300,100);
        getContentPane().add(sp);
        button.setBounds(300,100,200,200);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TC tc = new TC();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

I have search here and in Google, curiously I see more complicated cases where the "not updating the UI" part is alike, but my case is simpler.

I have read the [DOC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#uneditable) saying:

> Something else to watch out for — even for uneditable combo boxes — is
>   ensuring that your custom model fires list data events when the combo
>   box's data or state changes. Even immutable combo box models, whose
>   data never changes, must fire a list data event (a CONTENTS_CHANGED
>   event) when the selection changes. One way to get the list data event
>   firing code for free is to make your combo box model a subclass of
>   AbstractListModel.

But I think I am doing right here, because `DefaultComboBoxModel` extends `AbstractListModel`.

This line neither works.

```
combo.setSelectedItem(combo.getModel().getElementAt(0));
```

So, is there some hint for me? It must have something to do with the renderer, but I don't know what I did wrong. The `BasicComboboxRenderer` doesn't react when combo's `selectedIndex` changes?

Comment: Have you tried calling repaint(); after changing the selection?

Comment: `repaint()`, `updateUI()` neither work. I put them in the `actionPerformed()` part. I think them unnecessary.

Comment: Editor is only used for editing of a value in a cell. To do what you want you need to update the table model.

Comment: Well, I think I must object if you say editor is only for editing. If you run the example you will see it: commenting the line and combobox disappears. For tables with `JCombobox` editor is necessary.

Comment: The simpler form of `combo.setSelectedItem(combo.getModel().getElementAt(0));` is `combo.setSelectedIndex(0);` ..

Comment: I have asked a question that no one can find its duplicate. It's total valid and I get answer, upvoted 3 times. I want to ask why my question is downvoted without comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already said you need to update the model.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TC extends JFrame{
    JComboBox<String> combo;
    JTable table;
    public TC(){
        begin();
    }
    public void begin(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("nothing.");
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"});
        combo = new JComboBox<>(model);
        table = new JTable(new Object[2][2], new String[] {"Column One", "Column Two"});
        TableColumn col0 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        col0.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(combo));

        JButton button = new JButton("Clear");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
                    table.setValueAt(combo.getModel().getElementAt(0), i, 0);
                }
            }
        });


        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
//      getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout());

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
        sp.setBounds(0,0,300,100);
        getContentPane().add(sp);
        button.setBounds(300,100,200,200);
        getContentPane().add(button);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TC tc = new TC();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see it correct. I want to update the table by the real value in every cell, but you answer fills the table with "null". Now what I see in all the table is blank. What if I want ot reset the value of the first combobox to "one" and the next to "two"?

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! So, if I understand it well, the renderer of a cell, if is a Combobox, will not update itself, because the updating will be controlled by the table?

Comment: Combobox is not a renderer, it's editor. Renderer is a label. And the editor is temporary object which is used to change the current value. After editing is done the editor goes removed. For example, when you clicks the "Clear" button, the editor is removed.

Comment: OK now I get it, so to make the label-renderer changed, I must update the table to make it work? Is it documented in the JTable renderer part? I have checked it but I don't find a part when describing "if the data change comes somewhere other than the editor in a cell, we must use `setValueAt()` to update the label".

Comment: Renderer is also a temporary object. Always use the model to change  data in a table.

Comment: Another thing to note is: just `setSelectedIndex(x)` before updating the table model. I understand that by setting the selected index of the combobox, the table refreshes the view with the new index selected, not by `combo.getModel().getElementAt(0)`.